# How can I validate with JSON scheme if object is empty or have required properties?

Tags: json, validation, jsonschema, required

I want to validate a JSON array of objects with schema in function. These objects must have exactly one of these formats:

- empty object
- object with four properties

I tried to wrap required properties in `oneOf`, but I got the following error: `Invalid input: data[1].prop should match exactly one schema in oneOf`

```
{
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "prop": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "name": {
                        "prop1": "string"
                    },
                    "type": {
                        "prop2": "string"
                    },
                    "amount": {
                        "prop3": "number"
                    },
                    "operation": {
                        "prop4": "string"
                    }
                },
                "oneOf": [
                    { "required": ["prop1", "prop2", "prop3", "prop4"] },
                    { "required": [] }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would move the `oneOf` out so that it's just under the `items` keyword.

In one of the subschemas, you have the `properties` keyword along with the `required` keyword for those properties *plus* an `additionalProperties: false`.  This portion would satisfy the "exactly four properties" condition.

In the other subschema, just identify that it needs to be an object, but don't declare any properties.  Use `additionalProperties: false` in this one, too.  This satisfies the "empty object" condition.